# RestFul 2 Requests

Tags: java

When I do two requests at the same time my return is mixed.

I do my test putting on browser.

**TAB 1**

```
localhost:8089/WebApplication2/resources/teste1?rep=2&clone=2
RETURN
{"codRepresentante":2,"codRetWS":100,"msgRetWS":"WebService de teste consumido com sucesso"}
```

**TAB 2**

```
localhost:8089/WebApplication2/resources/teste1?rep=1&clone=1
RETURN
{"codRepresentante":2,"codRetWS":100,"msgRetWS":"WebService de teste consumido com sucesso"}
```

How can I fixed it?
Whats wrong on my code?

**RETORNO1WS.JAVA**

```
package base;
public final class Retorno1WS {
    private static int CodRetWS;
    private static int CodRepresentante;
    private static String MsgRetWS;

    public synchronized int getCodRetWS() {
        return Retorno1WS.CodRetWS;
    }

    public synchronized void setCodRetWS(int CodRetWS) {
        Retorno1WS.CodRetWS = CodRetWS;
    }

    public synchronized int getCodRepresentante() {
        return Retorno1WS.CodRepresentante;
    }

    public synchronized void setCodRepresentante(int CodRepresentante) {
        Retorno1WS.CodRepresentante = CodRepresentante;
    }

    public synchronized String getMsgRetWS() {
        return Retorno1WS.MsgRetWS;
    }

    public synchronized void setMsgRetWS(String MsgRetWS) {
        Retorno1WS.MsgRetWS = MsgRetWS;
    }

}
```

**TESTE1WS.JAVA**

```
package ws;

import base.Retorno1WS;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Stateless
@Path("/teste1")
public class Teste1WS  {

    /**
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public Teste1WS() throws SQLException, Exception {
        super();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public synchronized Retorno1WS getTeste(@DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("rep") int CodRep) {

            Retorno1WS RetWS1 = new Retorno1WS();
            RetWS1.setCodRetWS(100);
            RetWS1.setMsgRetWS("WebService de teste consumido com sucesso");
            RetWS1.setCodRepresentante(CodRep);     

            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((1500 - 500) + 1) + 500;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(randomNum);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Teste1WS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            return RetWS1;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're wondering why even though you're using synchronized around your stateless bean why you're still getting an essentially random snapshot of your static data? Is there a particular reason you really need the data to be static?

Comment: This is just for testing. On my server the return came from the database. 
I used the sleep method to simulate a long search.

Comment: Right, but the underlying question remains: you're using static data. Any time you modify it you're modifying it for *everyone*. I'm trying to understand why you think it'll work.

Comment: I'm asking *why* you're using static data.

Comment: Now i understood your question and I changed my code(RETORNO1WS.JAVA) for non static and everything works fine.

Thanks for your help